# Flash as2 using xml from dropbox and saving data via xml

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2, saving-data

I have been googling the crap out of this, and can't seem to find the answer. What I want is my flash to access a xml file on my dropbox account. Problem is I keep getting "Error opening URL...".  I am new to using XML in as2, so all I have is this snipet of tutorial code:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
myXML.load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30169277/onlinesaves/test.xml");
myXML.onLoad = function(success) {
if (success) {
var myImage = myXML.firstChild.childNodes;
for (i=0; i<myImage.length; i++) {
var imageNumber = i+1;
var imageName = myImage[i].attributes.title;
var imageURL = myImage[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
trace ("My image number "+imageNumber+" is titled "+imageName+" and its URL is "+imageURL+".")
}
}
};
```

I understand for security reasons that flash can only acces what is on the desktop, or same source folder for that matter, but I've seen it done before. And I know flash is attempting to open it, because every time I export, my dropbox lets me know 2 files had changed (the xml and the image).

So, I'd like to know how to get that fixed, and when fixed, how would I save flash data via the xml file to my drop box. Responses are much aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API does not support [ActionScript 2](https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-as3/wiki/README). In general, use the following process:

- Create a [crossdomain.xml](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00000469.html) policy file to load data from another domain
- Use [sendAndLoad](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001729.html) to POST data to another domain